# Sorting arrays in NumPy by column wrong

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, columnsorting

I have tested the following code

```
a=np.array([[1,5],[2,4]])
a[a[:,1].argsort()]
print(a)
```

And i receive

```
[[1,5],[2,4]]
```

I am supposed to obtain

```
[[2,4],[1,5]]
```

Numpy is imported as np.
What is going on?

Comment: `a[a[:,1].argsort()]` Doesn't change `a`. To change do `a = a[a[:,1].argsort()]`.

Comment: Thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 0):

The expression will get evaluated at interpreter level. But the actual value of 'a' will get modified once the assignment happens to the variable.

```
import numpy as np;
a=np.array([[1,5],[2,4]]);
a=a[a[:,1].argsort()];
print(a);
```

Comment: Why do you add the ';' at the end of the lines?

Comment: It is optional buddy... You may ignore the same...!